# Why does my query not work in any scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written a query picking those records who OPENING TIME is greater than the current time and the date difference between OPENING DATE and current date should be <=3 and >=0, actually for the purpose of notification popup which tells you which jobs are getting opened within 3 days. Once it gets opened then no records should be picked i.e. date difference is 0 and current time gets greater than the mentioned opening time.

Now my query works in some cases like picking records with <=3 and >=0 but not if current time gets greater than Opening Time for any day. Since I have used AND operator so it gets failed i.e. if Opening Time is 14:00 and current time gets 14:01 then <=3 and >=0 also fails.

My query:

```
Declare @NotificationAllowed bit
    Set @NotificationAllowed= ISNULL((Select NotificationAllowed from Roles where RoleID= @RoleID),0)

    IF @NotificationAllowed=1
    BEGIN
        Select  @NotificationAllowed as IsAllowed, Works.NIT_No, Works.WorkNo, Works.WorkName, DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) as TotalDaysRemaining 
                ,Convert(varchar(11), Works.OpeningDate, 106) as OpeningDate
        from Works
        Where DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) <=3
        AND 
        DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date,GETDATE()), Works.OpeningDate) >=0
        AND 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), Works.OpeningTime, 108) >  CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108) 
        AND
        Works.Organization_ID= Case When @RoleID=1  then Works.Organization_ID ELSE @OrgID end 
    END 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Select  0 as IsAllowed, '' AS NIT_No, ''  AS WorkNo, '' AS WorkName, '' as TotalDaysRemaining, null as OpeningDate
    END
```

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ :please look at this link to improve question

Comment: @TheGameiswar thanks sir, I will but for now can you help me with the question ?

Comment: this is not answerable,request you take some time to go through the link and reframe it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to work with date and time as separate fields, it would be better to put them together and just use the *datetime* data type. I've removed the OpeningTime field from your schema and use the OpeningDate as a datetime.

```
create table Works (
    NIT_No int,
    WorkNO int,
    WorkName varchar(32),
    OpeningDate datetime
)
```

Here's some example data that I used:

```
+ ------ + ------- + -------- + ----------------------- +
| NIT_No | Work_No | WorkName | OpeningDate             |
+ ------ + ------- + -------- + ----------------------- +
| 1      | 1       | Work1    | 2017-02-26 16:21:15.083 |
| 2      | 2       | Work2    | 2017-02-27 09:21:15.083 |
| 2      | 3       | Work3    | 2017-03-01 00:21:15.083 |
| 3      | 4       | Work4    | 2017-03-01 13:09:15.083 |
| 4      | 5       | Work5    | 2017-03-02 13:21:15.083 |
| 5      | 6       | Work6    | 2017-03-03 17:21:15.083 |
| 5      | 7       | Work7    | 2017-03-04 11:45:15.083 | 
| 5      | 8       | Work8    | 2017-03-04 19:21:15.083 |
+ ------ + ------- + -------- + ----------------------- +
```

You want to keep any records with opening date ahead of getdate and less than three days away *to the _____*. And here we fill in the blank. Do you care about being accurate to the *hour*, *minute*, *second*? This is left up to you and probably depends on your application. I'm going to use minutes. So I want to include dates between 0 and 3*24*60 minutes away from getdate. The following query does just that

```
Select  @NotificationAllowed as IsAllowed,
        NIT_No,
        WorkNo,
        WorkName,
        DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), OpeningDate) as TotalDaysRemaining,
        OpeningDate as OpeningDate
    from #Works
    Where DATEDIFF(Minute, GETDATE(), OpeningDate) between 0 and 3*24*60
```

When run it on Mar  1 2017 12:35PM, I get the following results

```
+ ------ + ------- + -------- + --- + ----------------------- +
| NIT_No | Work_No | WorkName | TDR | OpeningDate             |
+ ------ + ------- + -------- + --- + ----------------------- +
| 3      | 4       | Work4    | 0   | 2017-03-01 13:09:15.083 |
| 4      | 5       | Work5    | 1   | 2017-03-02 13:21:15.083 |
| 5      | 6       | Work6    | 2   | 2017-03-03 17:21:15.083 |
| 5      | 7       | Work7    | 3   | 2017-03-04 11:45:15.083 | 
+ ------ + ------- + -------- + --- + ----------------------- +
```

All you have to do is include the logical program flow and the extra filter for Organization_ID.